# React Router and Switch

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and i am trying to use Router, Switch and Layout as below. But it's showing white screen. If i remove the whole block div 'Main' then the navbar shows up if i add it back everything goes white. I couldn't find the error. Please give me some suggestions.

```
<div className='app'>
    <div className='navbar p-0 m-0'>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
    <div className='main'>
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <div className='routes'>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
                <Route exact path="/exchanges" component ={Exchanges} />
                <Route exact path="/cryptocurrencies" component={Cryptocurrencies} />
                <Route exact path="/crypto/:coinId" component ={CryptoDetails} />
                <Route exact path="/news" component ={News} />
              </Switch>
          </div>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </div>
    <div className='footer'>
    </div>
  </div>
```

index.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.js you also need to add
`import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`

and wrap app in :  `<BrowserRouter>`
e.g.
 `<BrowserRouter> <App /> </BrowserRouter>`

Answer (score 0):

Also, in the new react-router-dom v6, you should use

`<Routes>` instead of `<Switch>`, and element instead of component, like so:

```
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>} />
            <Route path="/exchanges" element ={<Exchanges/>} />
            <Route path="/cryptocurrencies" element={<Cryptocurrencies/>} />
            <Route exact path="/crypto/:coinId" element ={<CryptoDetails/>} />
            <Route path="/news" element={<News/>} />
          </Routes>
```

Also, "exact" keyword is no longer required.

Comment: Do we need to wrap routes by Router?

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't use "switch", I use "routes".

If you want to learn about it, see the following URL

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Good luck